# CSS Alter Existing Styles Only

Tags: html, css

The answer is probably no but I'll ask anyway. With CSS, is it possible to override existing styles only?

Example: change the border color of elements that do have borders and leave elements without borders alone.

Something like

```
div[border] {}
```

The code above should only alter the style of divs that do have a border style.
Is there anything like this or no?

Comment: No, it's not possible with CSS alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like explained in your question you cannot do such thing with CSS but if we think about this differently we can find another way. You may define styles using [CSS variables](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variable) and then by simply adjusting the value of the variable you will only alter the existing CSS.

Here is a simplified example:

```css
.class1 {
  border:1px solid var(--c,red);
}
.class2 {
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:5px;
  border-color:var(--c,red);
}
.class-dont-touch {
  border:2px solid red;
}

/* Change the value on the body and it will be inherited by the other element*/
body {
  --c:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
some content
</div>

<p class="class2">
more content
</p>

<p class="class-dont-touch">
content with border to not modify
</p>
```

So we only change the value of the variable within a parent container and all the values used will be changed. Like that only the needed styles are affected.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, Afif, but how does this answer the question? The question was: can I, using only CSS, overwrite a property to existing elements if the property has been set and not if the property hasn't? Setting the property using CSS variables is pretty much the same as using JavaScript variables or using php variables. It just happens at a different level, but still requires us to go through the code/app and say: i want it here, here and there. Which is not what was asked at all. The only answer is **NO**, because the property is set at all times to its default value. That's CSS!

Comment: I'm not saying what you propose is wrong. It's DRY and that's how programming should be done, regardless of language. But it's not directly connected to what was being asked. It would be fair to say you can't select all elements that have border in DOM, using a CSS selector. It would be nice, though, I admit :D...

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu: I think it could be made a little clearer that this only approximates what the asker wants and doesn't actually accomplish it directly.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I think my first sentence resume what you said. I said that what he want to do is **not possible** with the CSS, we all agree about this and I also upvoted your comment. Now I tried to guess his need and when he said he want to apply style to some element that have border so i thought he want to select only few of the elements in order to adjust their style and using CSS variable is somehing very close to what he want : You define a property using a particular variable then you simply change it to change all the properties affected.

Comment: and as @BoltClock said this is a way [maybe new to the asker] in order to handle his CSS. It has nothing to do with the question itself but it can be something to consider by the OP depending on his needs. By the way he accepted the answer so I guess *my guess* about his need was partially correct.

Comment: I saw what you answered and I know how CSS variables work ツ. I just say the question is interesting and got upvotes because it basically asks: *"is there a CSS selector that will apply Afif's variable without us (lazy coders) having to show it where to apply it?"* And the unfortunate answer is "*Don't be lazy, coder!*" So I'm a bit of a  disappointed monkey. I want to be lazy! I want to use the stick and get the bananas without having to climb up into the tree. ツ Cheers, man! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score -1):

This would work only if the styles were set as HTML attributes, e.g.

```
div[style*="border"] {
    border-color: #ffff00 !important;
}
```

Comment: This only overrides if the `border` was added inline. Not if set from a stylesheet and it's also going to be less specific than the inline rule itself.

Comment: Remember that inline styles overwrite this, so you'll have to append `!important` behind it.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, this is a working, legitimate answer.

Comment: @Roberrrt as Andrei said this will work only if the style is inline and guess what? this will also catch `border-radius`. So this won't work in all the cases

Comment: That's still 1) literally what Bram is stated here and 2), could still be  changed/experimented with/utilised by someone who is having a simular question.